# Understanding the Java Statement "Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);"

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain the syntax of this statement:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

I think it is saying "create a new instance of Button called myButton."  The equals sign would seem to indicate that myButton should be initialized to something, but my research seems to indicate the part after the equals sign is basically saying that this instance of myButton is hooked to the Button defined in a XML layout file.

?What is the point of the "(Button)" - it seems kind of redundant.

?Is myButton being initialized, of just hooked to the actual XML button?

?I'm searching and cannot find any description of a Java statement like this - is this unique to Android Java?  Can someone explain the syntax here?

Thx.

Comment: This is Java. Please learn Java before moving to the Android platform.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Basic understanding of Android.

Comment: 'Type Casting' or 'Casting' was what I needed.  Thx.

Answer (score 4):

`(Button)` it casting the `findViewById(R.id.my_button);` method to the Button  `myButton` Object

[**public View findViewById (int id)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

```
Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML 
that was processed in onCreate(Bundle)
```

Returns

```
The view if found or null otherwise.
```

Answer (score 3):

1.) `myButton` is a variable of type `Button`. This binding is made by declaring `Button myButton`.

2.) The `=` operator means assignment. You are assigning contents to the variable `myButton`.

**What are the contents of assignment?**

3.) An android widget which is returned using the method `findViewById()` [#findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)and then casted to a `Button` by saying `(Button)`

**So in conclusion**, you have a `Button` being assigned to `myButton`, and yes, the button is now hooked up to the xml button with the id that you pass to `findViewById()`

Answer (score 2):

Button is a view. findViewById(int id) will return the View given the view's id. Since findViewById only returns a View, you need to cast it to a Button so you can access the button specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's unsderstand, what is Button in android?

This is a syntax in XML which we use:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="CLICK ME!!" />
```

Now in `MainActivity.java`, here we use as

```
 Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button); //here we are invoking button ID from xml.
```

For `actionListener` we use here:

```
myButton.setOnClickEvent(new OnClickEvent(
          public void onClickEvent(View v){
            //DO SOMETHING AWESOME!
          }
        ));
```

for more info how actually it works for Button click [here](http://www.dinstuhl.org/?p=57)